# How do I attach a right click event to a draggable div

Tags: jquery, click, mouse

This is the problem I am having. I need to attach some kind of handle to a draggable div.

What I need to do is capture the right mouse button every time that I right click on div within the parent.

This is my child creation code.  This code works fine and I can create multiple div without a problem.

```
var smallBlock = $('<div class="SmallBlock"></div>').appendTo("#canvas");
smallBlock..draggable({containment: "#canvas", scroll: false, grid: [10, 10]}, {cursor: "move", cursorAt: {top: 125, left: 150}})
smallBlock.append('<div class="article_title fontCenter fontBold font32">Article Title</div>')
smallBlock.append('<div class="article_Image"><img style="width: 250px;" src="<? echo $image1 ?>"></div>')
smallBlock.append('<div class="font14"><? echo substr($article_text, 0, 200) ?></div>')
```

And this is the mouse click code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getRightClick()
{
    // check for right mouse pressed

$('#canvas').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left mouse button pressed');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right mouse button pressed');
           break;
        default:
            alert('You have a strange mouse');
    }
});
}

</script>
```

I have no idea how to make the get the div to recognize that a right mouse was clicked over it.

BTW, there are other classes of divs within the parent which I need to detect; so a more general solution might be better.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672684/can-we-make-jquery-ui-draggables-sortables-to-work-on-right-mouse-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add this to the context id element:

```
oncontextmenu="alert('right click on element');return false;
```

or perhaps this:

```
jQuery('#yourDIVId').mousedown(function(event) {
   var rightclk = false;
   if (event.which) rightclick = (event.which == 3);
     if(rightclk == true){
        alert('yes')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this out after dinner :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#canvas").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
  alert('Right mouse clicked'); 
});
```

Comment: Where should I be placing this code?  I have tried in the <head> and also inside the canvas div, but nothing appears.  Do I need to create an actual context menu?

Comment: I like Arons too. more succinct.

Comment: Place it in the head in a script tag and wrap it in document ready, so it would like this: `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
  // here comes the previous javascript code
}); </script>`

Comment: Works for now, Thanks so much Aron

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#page').ready(function() {
        $('#page').bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
            alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
            /*you can replace the alert with any function that you want to bind with right click
             */
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id='page'>
        <div id="divParent">click parent
            <div id="divChild">click child</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</body>
```

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/rLJMh/258/)