# Can We Make JQuery UI Draggables / Sortables To Work On Right Mouse Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page that has functions bind to both left and right mouse button, ie. draggable/sortable on left mouse button, and custom context menu on right mouse button.

What I want to do is switch the functions so that context menu works on left mouse button clicks and JQuery UI Draggable/Sortable works on right mouse button click.

Thanks for any help.

PS: I can make the custom context menu to work on left mouse button. So I only need help with the JQuery UI Draggable/Sortable only. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of creating a custom build of jQuery UI, and modifying files directly, you can just extend draggable (and sortable, if you need to), to allow right mouse clicks. All of the mouse interactions in jQuery UI are handled by Mouse Widget ($.ui.mouse). And draggable widget is extending mouse widget. So in a nutshell, draggable has all the same methods that mouse does. If you override those on the draggable prototype ($.ui.draggable.prototype) then you can get your functionality on all draggable objects without having to modify jQuery UI files.

It's generally not a great idea to modify 3rd party frameworks directly, since it will prevent you from upgrading, or will require you to copy your changes every time you upgrade.

The main idea is to override a few functions:

```
$.extend($.ui.draggable.prototype, {...});
```

Here's a working example of the modified draggable: http://jsfiddle.net/NjXdv/4/
It takes an extra parameter: mouseButton. If you don't pass anything in, it will use left mouse button. If you pass 3 in, it will use right mouse button. You can also try to pass 2 for middle button.

P.S. This will stop context menu from opening only on the elements that you care about, instead of disabling it on the whole page.

**Update:**

If you want to enable all jQuery UI controls to have the ability to work with a different mouse button, then instead of extending draggable, you should extend mouse itself. As I said before, every single jQuery UI control reads mouse events from the $.ui.mouse, so if you override that, it will cascade to every control. Here's updated example with both sortable and draggable: http://jsfiddle.net/NjXdv/7/. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, ie. something that I can extend/override the main events without touching the core JQuery UI files.

Sorry but I am new to JQuery UI or javascript, but how do I make it work for both draggable and sortable?

Comment: Updated my answer with the sortable example too.

Comment: Also, you still have to watch out for jQuery updates. Because I had to more or less copy the whole _mouseDown function (no other way around it, really), everytime jQuery UI updates that function, you have to update your code too. Luckily, they don't do that very often.

Answer (score 11):

Actually is not possible without hacking the jQuery UI code.

I don't know why you want to use this behavior because can confuse your final users, but here is a possible solution.

Starting from this jQuery UI ticket http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6909 I build up a custom version of jQuery UI.
So you have to use a modified version of the library.

I disable the browser right click default menu for the whole page using:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

or referring to a specific element:

```
$("#sortable").bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Here are the two main custom edits to jQuery UI code.

In `ui.mouse` default options add the option:

> which:1

From jQuery UI reference:

> which (Number) Default: 1
>
> A number that matches the "which" event property to indicate the
>   mousebutton that is pressed. (0 = Any Button, 1 = Left Button, 2 =
>   Middle Button, 3 = Right Button)

In function `_mouseDown` change the code to read this option:

```
tnIsLeft = (event.which == this.options.which) // instead of this (event.which == 1)
```

In theory in future version of jQuery UI this will be supported without any hack.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/nLdLu/

### EDIT

Following there is a pastebin version with right click mod including:

> - Includes: jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.ui.mouse.js, jquery.ui.position.js, jquery.ui.draggable.js,
>     jquery.ui.droppable.js, jquery.ui.resizable.js,
>     jquery.ui.selectable.js, jquery.ui.sortable.js

Link: http://pastebin.com/nn3Pj0pM

Usually a modded copy is not a great thing, you can also extend and override the two functions needed to let the right mouse button works, but the main problem remains: if you upgrade jQuery UI you have to check compatibility or port your mods into newer version. For what I see jQuery UI 2.x will support the `which` implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My guess on why he would want this behavior - a left handed mode? The reason I think of this is that one of my users has that feature turned on in Windows - every time I sit down at her machine I spend 2 minutes trying to figure out why nothing is working.

Comment: Kudos for hacking the core!

Answer (score 1):

From JQuery Ui core File

```
$.extend( $.ui, {
    version: "1.8.23",

    keyCode: {
        ALT: 18,
        BACKSPACE: 8,
        CAPS_LOCK: 20,
        COMMA: 188,
        COMMAND: 91,
        COMMAND_LEFT: 91, // COMMAND
        COMMAND_RIGHT: 93,
        CONTROL: 17,
        DELETE: 46,
        DOWN: 40,
        END: 35,
        ENTER: 13,
        ESCAPE: 27,
        HOME: 36,
        INSERT: 45,
        LEFT: 37,
        MENU: 93, // COMMAND_RIGHT
        NUMPAD_ADD: 107,
        NUMPAD_DECIMAL: 110,
        NUMPAD_DIVIDE: 111,
        NUMPAD_ENTER: 108,
        NUMPAD_MULTIPLY: 106,
        NUMPAD_SUBTRACT: 109,
        PAGE_DOWN: 34,
        PAGE_UP: 33,
        PERIOD: 190,
        RIGHT: 39,
        SHIFT: 16,
        SPACE: 32,
        TAB: 9,
        UP: 38,
        WINDOWS: 91 // COMMAND
    }
});
```

if we swap keycode of LEFT AND RIGHT then it may work ..

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, which has nothing to do with using the keyboard to begin with. The OP is asking how to make the plugins work with the alternative _mouse_ button.

Comment: that is i am saying .. open resizables' init handler and change the left and right mouse point. it is surely works. or you can extend resizable and do the same and use that after it.. am i wrong!!...

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Keycodes 91 and 93, which you are indicating to be the left and right mouse buttons are codes for the WIN key (Start Menu) in Windows. If you want to respond to Mouse events, you use ... Mouse events - not keyCodes, which are for Keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 1) {
        $('#element').draggable();
        $('#element').sortable();
    } else if (event.which == 3) {
        // context menu functions
    }
});
```